# TwitPic filter by hashtag

Tags: twitpic

I want to display twitPic photos with the hashtag of #animals. Currently, I am displaying photos through the username. This is my code below:

```
 $username = "smcsconverse";

//this is your twitpic RSS feed...
$yourRSS = "http://twitpic.com/photos/".$username."/feed.rss";
```

However, I am now stuck with how retrieving pictures through a given hashtag. I have been stuck quite awhile on this.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like twit pic has added a beta hashtag search. [Here](http://dev.twitpic.com/docs/2/tags_show/) is the documentation.